# In quantum teleportation, should the X gate be before Z gate? Possible error on diagram on QisKit website

Tags: qiskit

I was reading this page about Quantum Teleportation :-
https://web.archive.org/web/20200831155725/https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/defining-quantum-circuits.html
Following this quantum circuit diagram, I calculated the quantum states (from left to right as it process thru the diagram) but for the case of classical bits result of 11, I find that if I perform Z gate before X gate (as the diagram is drawn), Bob's get the wrong qubit by a factor of -1.
The matrix for performing Z before X is this :-
( 0,-1)
( 1, 0)
The matrix for performing X before Z is this :-
( 0, 1)
(-1, 0)
I get the right qubit for Bob if I do X before Z.
So I need someone to double-check the calculations again.
Is the diagram on QisKit web-site correct?
Thanks.

Comment: just so you know, gates don't generally commute, order always matter, as you may already know quantum gates can be represented as matrices, right? Matrices simply  do not commute and so are the quantum gates (there are some few exceptions that commute tho).

Answer (score 2):

The diagram in that specific section of the textbook is incorrect, and if you go to the Quantum Teleportation Chapter of the Qiskit Textbook, you will see that X comes before Z. The reason that the diagram you referenced is incorrect is because, as you just showed, XZ (performing Z before X) is not equal to ZX (performing X before Z), and ZX gives the correct result, meaning the order matters and X should be applied before Z. I've brought up this issue on Github which you can view at the following link: https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-textbook/issues/714

Comment: Thanks for confirming that the first diagram is incorrect. Hope the authors will fix it for future readers and avoid the confusion I had. Thanks again.

Comment: This is a late update, but the authors have fixed the issue! If you find errors like that in the future, you can always write an issue at https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-textbook

Comment: Not sure if they have fixed it or not, but in November 2023 it's the same diagram as in August 2020: https://qiskit.org/documentation/qc_intro.html